# How to store static content across branches in a single location in version control

Tags: svn, version-control, optimization, web-applications, branch

[Just a random thought]

I have a pdf doc that is downloaded when the user clicks on 'help' on my website. Now, this is a pretty huge document and is saved in version control (SVN) and is thus copied for all branches that exist in SVN. This is static content and something that developers are not working on, and does not change often. Is there a more efficient way to store it (that would not hamper local deployments) that would make SVN checkouts and updates relatively faster.

I know the benefit we get is not huge, this is something that came to my head none the less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your pdf in separate dir:

```
/trunk
/branches
/doc <- here it is
```

and then “mount” it to your working copies using [SVN’s externals mechanism](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html)

Comment: In this case too, when ever I take an update on the folder whose SVN:external are set, that would download this pdf for each of my branches? I was shooting in the dark when I was hoping if there were a mechanism for local deployments to pull the pdf from SVN directly when user clicks on 'help', and that the pdf does not actually reside on local machine.

Comment: Yes, it will download it once and then every time it is get updated. If you want to fetch it on first access, I think there is no trivial way to do this. Maybe SVN mapped WebDAV drive could help you with this, but I think it is over-engineering for your problem

Comment: Thanks ! I will read about SVN mapped WebDAV, as frankly I am not very sure what it is. This looks like the most helpful answer I can get :) so am marking it as appropriate

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create the following structure under trunk

```
/trunk
   +-- doc 
   +-- src
```

This means every developer can checkout trunk/src do branching as always (svn cp ^/trunk ^/branches/NEWBRNACH) etc. If you need to change the doc just checkout trunk/doc instead...I would prefer that, cause the doc is in relation with your project and is under change like the source code.